# Internal DSL in Scala tuple to a class conversion

Tags: scala, dsl

I'm trying to build an internal DSL in Scala. I have the following types:

```
case class A(name:String)
case class Group(list:A*) // it can also be list:List[A]
```

Creating a group of A's using the normal syntax is as follows:

```
val group1 = Group(A("a1"), A("a2"), ...)
```

which is quite ugly. I would like to present a group as `(A("a1"), A("a2"), ...)` and possibly later `("a1", "a2", ...)`, if possible.

I could not figure it out myself how to convert `(A("a1"), A("a2"), ...)` to `Group(A("a1"), A("a2"), ...)`.  It would be nice if we can convert `(A("a1"), A("a2"), ...)` to an instance of class Group. (I don't care if I can't specify unlimited number of A's inside. Maximum 8 A's will suffice)

So my question is: Is there a way to convert a tuple to a specific instance of a class? If not, how would you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, solving something for tuples of *any arity* in Scala is nasty because the tuple classes are distinct, so you'd have to have 8 or 22 or whatever arity you want to support conversions.

But anyways, tuples are for heterogeneously typed things, whereas you here require a collection of a common type. So while tuple syntax may look nice, I would recommend not to try to use it for this case in your DSL. Stick to collections or just alias your `Group` type, even at the price of an additional character, e.g.

```
object A {
  implicit def fromString(name: String) = A(name)
}
case class A(name: String)
case class Group(elem: A*)

val G = Group
G("a1", "a2")
```

---

If you really want to support tuples, the following will do:

```
object Group {
  implicit def fromTuple2[A1 <% A, A2 <% A](t: (A1, A2)) = Group(t._1, t._2)
}
case class Group(elem: A*)

("a1", "a2"): Group
```